# Show that a finite field of order $p^n$ has exactly one subfield of $p^m$ elements for each divisor $m$ of $n$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Show that a finite field of order $p^n$ has exactly one subfield of $p^m$ elements for each divisor $m$ of $n$.

Suppose that $o(F)=p^n$ .Let $F$ has $\Bbb Z_p$ as its prime subfield. Let $n=km$. I will have to construct a subfield of order $p^m$.Frankly speaking I have not done enough to show you all.I could not get further .

I am finding it difficult where to start the problem.Any hints will be helpful

Comment: To begin with, a finite field of order $p^m$ (isomorphically) comprises all the roots of $x^{p^m}-x$ in $\bar{\Bbb Z}_p$.

Comment: but there is no satisfactory answer to that question ?@rschwieb

Comment: that does not mean you give up on the first post and proceed to litter more copies elsewhere. It means you work on improving the post and incentivizing it.

Comment: You reask (never a good idea)! And after 11 frigging hours!? Just work on the previous version. It often takes days for the best answers to come. Why do you think your question would be an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $S_m(F)=\{a\in F:a^{p^m}=a\}$

**Step 1**: Check that $S_m(F)$ is a subfield of $F$.Note that $0\in S_m(F)$ ;$o(S_m(F))\leq p^m\implies o(S_m^*(F))\leq p^m-1$
 where $(S_m^*(F))$ denotes set of all non -zero elements of $(S_m(F))$

**Step 2**:Let $n=md$;  $p^n-1=(p^m-1)(1+p^m+...)\implies p^m-1|p^n-1$.Consider $F^*$.We have $|F^*|=p^n-1$ and it is cyclic .So it has a unique subgroup of order $p^m-1$ and all its elements satisfy $x^{p^m}=x$.So we have exactly $p^m$ elements in $(S_m(F))$.So we get a subfield of order $p^m$.

Comment: If you are going to post a solution, please post it on the first copy that the person posted rather than encouraging this behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the person that cast the downvote.

Comment: how can you show that $S_m  (F)$ is a sub field? @Learnmore

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Such a field is the splitting field of $X^{p^n}-X=0$ and contains the splitting field of $X^{p^m}-X$ if $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: What is a splitting field ?I am reading Fraleigh ;there is still no term upto section 33 in it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_p \leq \mathbb{Z}_{p^n} \leq \overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$. Where the $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Note that elements of the middle $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ are those $p^n$ zeros of $x^{p^n}-x \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$.

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ contains two or more subfields $A_1,...,A_L,L\geq2$ of order $p^m$, then contradiction arises. Because those elements inside $A_l$ must satisfy $x^{p^m}-x=0.$ (This is because the units of a finite field form a cyclic group.) However, inside the largest $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$ we can have $p^m$ such elements. Hence the only thing we need to care about is the existence.

Choose a generator $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}^\times$. Then forall $a^j$, where $j \in \{1,2,...,p^n-1\}$, it is a root of $x^{p^m}-x=0 \iff jp^m-1 \equiv 0 \mod p^n-1.$ In other words, $j=k\cdot \frac{p^n-1}{p^m-1}$ for some appropriate $k\in \mathbb{Z}.$ Note that $\frac{p^n-1}{p^m-1}$ is an integer if $m$ divides $n$, because we can always factor the denominator from the numerator. Note that $k$ can be $1,2,...,p^m-1$.

Hence we have $p^m$ elements ($p^m-1$ nonzero elements plus the $0$) inside $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ satisfies $x^{p^m}-x=0,$ which exhausts all possible roots in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_p$. And they forms a subfield of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$. We are done.