# How can I prove that any field of order $p^n$ has a unique subring of order $p^m$ where $m$ divides $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

How can I prove that any field of order $p^n$ has a unique subring of order $p^m$ where $m$ divides $n$.  I understand that there is a unique subfield of order $p^m$ for every $m$. But I can not see that there is no other subring of order $p^m$.

Can anyone please explain me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608204/show-that-a-finite-field-of-order-pn-has-exactly-one-subfield-of-pm-elemen    can you please check this question and answers..@ChrisGodsil

Comment: By the way I said m divides n...@ChrisGodsil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subring of a finite field is a field. If $a$ is a nonzero element of a finite field $F$, then $a^n=1$ for some $n>0$, so $a^{n-1}=a^{-1}$. Any subring of $F$ containing $a$
therefore contains $a^{-1}$.